# I run a maven project with the package goal. I defined the main class in the manifest but I still cannot have the jar file run in command prompt. Why?

Tags: maven, manifest, pom.xml, executable-jar

I run a maven project with the package goal. I got a .jar file. I defined the main class in the manifest (see code snippet below) but I still cannot have the jar file run in command prompt. (java -jar jarfile-src.jar). It writes 'no main manifest attribute, in jarfile-src.jar'. But as you see I defined the main class. It is a class called Main, in the package 'org.jis'.

```
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>swt1</groupId>
    <artifactId>iMage</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <groupId>swt1.ub1.a1</groupId>
  <artifactId>2056751</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <configuration>
          <archive>
          <manifestFile>src/main/resources/MANIFEST.MF</manifestFile>
          <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
          </manifest>
          </archive>
          </configuration>

  </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Main-class attribute in plugin configuration of maven jar plugin and ensure it is getting correctly reflected in generated manifest.mf.

Example:Assuming *learn.maven.HelloWorld* is a class containing main method.
Put the following code in your pom and fire the command : *mvn clean install*

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>learn.maven.HelloWorld</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can see in generated jar, the manifest.mf file will look like following.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: shinchan  
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.2.1
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_131
Main-Class: learn.maven.HelloWorld
```

Run the jar with command : *java -jar jarname.jar*

Comment: Dou you mena  something like that:  

        <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainclass>org.jis.Main</mainclass>
          </manifest>

I am using it, but still getting the same error.

Comment: Why are you providing the path of existing manifest ? Let the maven create its own manifest.

Comment: Hi Shinchan, if I remove it I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @ArminBeda Updated the answer with exact details to put in pom. This should work.

Comment: hi Sinchan, it still does not work. I am using exactly the same lines in the pom.xml as you are, still the content of my manifest does not change. Do you have any idea why is it like that?

Comment: Is there any existing manifest in your project structure that gets somehow  copied to final jar ? Can you try creating a brand new project with one main class only and check if it works ? I just tried and it worked.